# Sequelize relation helper method returning null immediately after insertion

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently experiencing a weird issue with my code regarding sequelize association. I have the following relationships defined:

```
Recipe.associate = function (models) {
    Recipe.belongsTo(models.User)
}

User.associate = function (models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Recipe)
}
```

I can get the related model using `recipe.getUser()` only if a retrieve the recipe with `Recipe.findById(id)`. But if I try doing `recipe.getUser()` immediately after inserting a recipe using:

```
const recipe = await Recipe.create({ userId, title, ingredients, direction})
const user = await recipe.getUser()
console.log(user)
```

This returns `null`, which I can't wrap my head around why it's so.

Comment: My assumption not really knowing sequelize is that when you create the recipe object, it does not populate the associated user at that time.  You would then have to use the created recipe id to findById to retrieve the recipe and all associations.  There appears to be a logged issue about this https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3807

Comment: There exists a user already in the database, which I'm using to create the recipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it. Seauelize does some magic underneath with it naming convention. So in my case, it's looking for a `UserId` (since I define my model as `User`) column on my `Recipe` model, of which I have defined as `userId`. So all I need to do is explicitly specify the correct column while defining the association:

```
Recipe.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
```

I have to put it out here in case someone else ever gets stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the console.log(user) is executing before the user is getting the response back from recipe.getUser().

Maybe try this:

```
const recipe = await Recipe.create({ userId, title, ingredients, direction})
const user = await recipe.getUser()
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Since I'm awaiting the query, that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: Have you confirmed the records are being added to the database? If you wrap the console.log statement in a Timeout just to test for a timing issue, does it return the expected result?

Comment: Yeah, the record is inserted in the database. I haven't tried the timeout

Comment: I have tried `then().catch()` in the insertion to see if there are any errors, but there are none.